# After using split() Array Index Out Of Bounds but reads array in loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, split

I'm writing a java code which reads text from file in columns, however when trying to run the code an out of bounds error shows. This happens only when I try to use a command: arr[1] (or higher index). The strange thing is that the following code works fine:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
public class ReadingColumns {
public static void run(){
  BufferedReader br = null;
    String[] characters = new String[10000];

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\wyn_005 trans.tif.txt"));

        int i=0;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] arr = sCurrentLine.split("\\t");

            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
                System.out.println(arr[j]);
            }
           // System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
          //  System.out.println("arr[0] = " + arr[0]); 
           //  System.out.println(arr[2]);

            i++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}}
```

`
The loop works fine (gives entire row one element by one, then next row in next while loop iteration and so on) and if I try to enter by using arr[0] it is also fine, but gives only the first column.

```
`System.out.println(sCurrentLine)`
```

gave whole file so I knew it wasn't missing anything. 
The file looks more or less like this:

```
Frame             X1   Y1   Marker1 R1    X2   Y2  Marker2 R2...
Data from 1 to 20
1                 1.0  2.0          3.2  4.0   3.1    *    5.5
2                 3.3  1.2          4.1  1.1   2.1         1.3
...
```

(Sorry, I didn't know how to make columns separated by tab here so it's made with spaces.)
Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I'm rather new to java so maybe I'm missing something simple.

Edit:
Exception is thrown when I uncomment line System.out.println(arr[2]); 
System.out.println(arr.length); gives 133 on every while iteration.

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? Have no clue what we should look into in this question. If throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for arr[1] then the array has only one element (arr.length is 1).

Comment: Where is the code that's not working fine?

Comment: Move the file to different drive than C:\\. Java has problems accessing System drive in Windows, so your array could very well be null, because the breader could not open the file..

Comment: The exception is thrown at the commented line: System.out.println(arr[2]); The arr.length is 133. I can't move to a different drive.

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting on a tab.   If arr[1], but arr[0] works, then sCurrentLine doesn't contain a tab.  if you're using

```
for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
```

then inside the loop you should't be using anything > arr.length, which in this error case, is 1.  So you can use arr[j] safely, but you cannot arbitrarily use any arr[number] unless you verify that number is within range (0, arr.length).

Comment: System.out.println(arr.length); gives me 133 on every while iteration. The loop works fine and doesn't throw an exception. I can't get the value by writing arr[2].

Answer (score 0):

Your file may not contain tab characters, but 4 spaces instead for indenting columns. That is why splitting by tab character gives you array of size 1. Try to split on this pattern:

```
sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
```

This pattern includes space and tab characters.

Comment: System.out.println(arr.length); gives me 133 on every while iteration (so it does'n change size). Spaces don't throw the exception but I don't get the right column. I get: Frame, 20(from "Data form 1 to 20"), then the R1 column for arr[3].